# How to scroll the screen options inside the drawer navigator in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**I have many screen options in my drawer navigator. As such I want to scroll down to see that what are the screens are available. So 
I want to scroll the screen options inside the drawer navigator. So how to  scroll the drawer navigator to see all other screen options**

```
const LeftNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: BottomNavigator,
          navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
            drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
              <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="BottomNavigator" title="Home" />
            )
          })
        },
      BankAndFinanceScreen: {
        screen: BankAndFinanceScreenDrawerStack,
          navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
            drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
              <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="BankAndFinanceScreenDrawerStack" title="Bank & Finance" />
            )
          })
        },
      ComplaintScreen: {
        screen: ComplaintScreenStack,
         navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
            drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
              <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="ComplaintScreenStack" title="Complaints" />
            )
          })
      },
      UserProfile: {
        screen: UserProfileStack,
        navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
          drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
            <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="UserProfileStack" title="User Profile" />
          )
        })
      },
      ClaimRefund: {
        screen: ClaimRefundStack,
        navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
          drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
            <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="ClaimRefundStack" title="Claim Refund" />
          )
        })
      },
      },
      ContactUsScreen: { screen: ContactUsScreenStack,
         navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
            drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
              <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="ContactUsScreenStack" title="Contact Us" />
            )
          })
      },    
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set your custom drawer menu component in the main config object in react navigation's drawer menu

```
export default DrawerNavigator({
    // screen 1
    // screen 2
    // screen 3
    // etc..
}, 
{   
    // set navigations config here
    // item below will be your custom drawer
    contentComponent: props => 
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
      <Text>Your Own Footer Area After</Text>
    </ScrollView>
});
```

check react-navigation docs for further details:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html